# Removing Where Clause at the Select Clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL Code:

```
Select count(City), count("All" Cities) from table1
Where City=London
```

At the "Select Clause" only city with the name London are showed.
But is it possible to make additional calculation at the select clause with all city. Not only City with the name "London"? Is it possible to remove the where clause but only in one select column?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to make additional calculation but without with all city for example count (city) not only city with the name London.

Comment: It still depends on what exactly you want. For example: `select city, (select count(*) from table1) as all_city_cnt from table1 where city = 'London'`

Comment: For example this one:     Select count(City), count("All" Cities) from table1 Where City=London.

Comment: Well you should be able to adjust the example above to get that result by adding `count(city)`.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you are after is 1 conditional aggregate, and one not:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE City WHEN 'London' THEN 1 END) AS London,
       COUNT(*) AS Cities
FROM dbo.Table1;
```

Comment: You right. One column conditional aggregate and one column non conditional aggregate. Is it only possible with the case function? It would be great to place the condition in the where clause.

Comment: The `WHERE` is the wrong place, @Freddy . The `WHERE` filters the rows **prior** to the `SELECT`. If you want rows to be considered in the `SELECT`, don't filter them in the `WHERE`.